# Android Status bar and Navigation issues

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

Recently I used this java code in `Main_Activity`:

```
(getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS))
```

for status Bar Transparent purpose. All went well, but my Android Navigation Bar also went to transparent policy.
Now I need only transparent my Status Bar, but not the Navigation Bar.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do, first, one which I recommend for you would be using an external library for status-bar styling like [StatusBarUtil](https://github.com/laobie/StatusBarUtil) library, which enables you to fulfill your requirement in just one line:

```
StatusBarUtil.setTransparent(Activity activity) // yo be placed in every activity you want the status bar to be transparent in
```

And this library doesn't affect the navigation bar.

Just make sure first to implement the library in your app level **Gradle**:

```
implementation'com.jaeger.statusbarutil:library:1.5.1'
```

---

Second option, is to go for layout customization, as mentioned in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@manishgiri/android-transparent-status-bar-part-1-989e16b11785), you can add the following to your `style.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.TransparentTheme">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And apply this style to the Activity in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".HomeActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransparentTheme">
</activity>
```

As described in the tutorial:

> I have set android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds to true.
>
> This is a flag whose description is given below:
>
> Flag indicating whether this Window is responsible for drawing the
>   background for the system bars. If true and the window is not
>   floating, the system bars are drawn with a transparent background and
>   the corresponding areas in this window are filled with the colors
>   specified in {@link android.R.attr#statusBarColor} and {@link
>   android.R.attr#navigationBarColor}. Corresponds to {@link
>   android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS}.

Don't forget to add the attribute `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the top root of your activity layout.

Comment: Its not working . I'm using Second option. It is makes my Status bar color white

Comment: You are right, just forgot to add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in my answer,have a look at the last line I added in my answer

Comment: Same not working. I add this code on my Activity_mainLayout Constraint Layout Part

Comment: you are you added it in the main root element of the activity ? if so and it is still not working, I advice you to try the library I mentioned.

Comment: Remember that the root layout should be a CoordinatorLayout in option 2